# How do I solve this integer programming problem with non convex constraints?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this question, please point me to the correct forum if I posted in a wrong place.

I have an optimization problem like this

```
Min sum(yi)
st  sum on j(wij) <= cyi for all i in N
    sum on i(xij) = 1 for all j in N
    wij = wjxij for all i, j in N
    Lij = Ljxij for all i, j in N
    Dij = Lij + wij for all i, j in N
    (Lij - Dik)(Lik - Dij) <= 0 for all i, j, k in N
    Aj <= Lj for all j in N
    Lj <= Aj + Qj for all j in N
    xij = 0 or 1 for all i, j in N
    yi = 0 or 1 for all i in N
    Wj, Lj, Qj and c are constant
    N = 10000
```

What can I do to transform this problem into a convex optimization problem? Or to a linear Integer programming problem? Because I only know algorithms to solve problems in those two categories.

In the problem, the only constraint that is not convex is this one

```
(Lij - Dik)(Lik - Dij) <= 0 for all i, j, k in N
```

Are there any common ways to transform this constraint into some convex constraints?

I think implicit enumeration could be a solution to this, but other than that, what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonlinear constraint
$$(L_{ij} - D_{ik})(L_{ik} - D_{ij}) \le 0$$
is a disjunction:
$$\left(L_{ij} - D_{ik} \ge 0 \wedge L_{ik} - D_{ij} \le 0\right) \bigvee \left(L_{ij} - D_{ik} \le 0 \wedge L_{ik} - D_{ij} \ge 0\right).$$
Introduce a binary variable $z_{ijk}$ that enforces at least one side of the disjunction.  We want:
\begin{align}
z_{ijk} = 1 &\implies (L_{ij} - D_{ik} \ge 0 \wedge L_{ik} - D_{ij} \le 0)\\
z_{ijk} = 0 &\implies (L_{ij} - D_{ik} \le 0 \wedge L_{ik} - D_{ij} \ge 0).
\end{align}
The following linear "big-M" constraints do the job:
\begin{align}
D_{ik} - L_{ij} &\le (L_k + W_k) (1 - z_{ijk})\\
L_{ik} - D_{ij} &\le L_k (1 - z_{ijk})\\
L_{ij} - D_{ik} &\le L_j z_{ijk}\\
D_{ij} - L_{ik} &\le (L_j + W_j) z_{ijk}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it... How does big M lead to the linear constraint that you were getting? I mean, I get your point, but I don't know how to come up with the linear constraints

Comment: The general "big-M" approach to enforce $y=1 \implies f(x) \le 0$ is $f(x) \le M(1-y)$, where $M$ is a (preferably small) upper bound on $f(x)$ when $y=0$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now

Comment: Do you have any good material regarding to linearization?

Comment: *Model Building in Mathematical Programming* by H. Paul Williams.  All 29 examples are demonstrated in the [SAS/OR documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ormpex&docsetTarget=titlepage.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en).